# HtmlAgilitypack fails to load certain html code. Causes unhandled .net Framework exception in w3wp.exe

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack, w3wp

Ive managed to finally isolate a issue I have with `HtmlAgilityPack`.

For a while, my `w3wp` has crashed causing a `unhandled .net Framework exception` to occur and the application pool restarts.

After using Debug Diagnostic i found that the problem occurs when trying to load the html result of this link:

https://tourette-syndrom.de/eingangsseite.htm

After viewing the source code i found that there are a big amount of `<o:p>` nodes that never closes, this causes the parser to fail.

I use the `LoadHtml`, this is something I need to use.

If i make use of `htmlDoc.Load` and pass the URI link instead of the html string, 
it generates a error im able to catch.

`System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks`

The error tells me nothing really, but the `w3wp` application does not crash!

Ive tested these option to both `true` and `false` but application still crashes.

```
 htmlDoc.OptionFixNestedTags
 htmlDoc.OptionAutoCloseOnEnd
 htmlDoc.OptionWriteEmptyNodes
```

If I simply replace the nodes `<o:p>` like this `htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlString.Replace("<o:p>",""))` then everything goes well. Im not looking for a simple replace function here, plus, this happends on several badly formatted websites, so was hoping this is something I can resolve by a proper setting or extension methods. Anyone else that have the same issue?

Comment: Is that `o:`  definined as an XML namespace?

Comment: @bommelding I have no idea, ive never seen the node before: view-source:https://tourette-syndrom.de/eingangsseite.htm

Comment: The top comment suggest the page started as an email (ouch). That `o:` is from a surrounding frame or template. Bottom line: It is old and invalid html. You will probably need per-site cleaning to make this work. An btw, I would replace `<o:p>` with `<p>`